# Conflict with subcaption and sublisting?

Tags: listings, subcaption

In the code below, partially derived from [Split subfigures from pgfplots groupstyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283680/split-subfigures-from-pgfplots-groupstyle), I am not able to compile my code when I include the sublisting environment.  I need this listing for my Python code sublisting.

Can you help me resolve the error that I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@sublisting already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[%
    ,top=3cm
    ,bottom=3cm
    ,left=3.2cm
    ,right=3.2cm
    ,headsep=10pt
    ,a4paper
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    ,compat=1.12
    ,minor grid style={dashed,red}
    ,major grid style={dotted,green!50!black}
    }
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=it,textfont=it,labelformat=parens,labelsep=space}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{listings}

%========================================================================================
%   Python and C++ Code Environment
%========================================================================================

\usepackage[pygopt={texcomments=true,style=emacs}]{pythontex}
\setpythontexlistingenv{listing}

\newcounter{sublisting}[listing]
\newcommand{\codeline}[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{lopytx}{listing}%
    {\protect\numberline{\hspace{0.5in}\thelisting.\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}\hspace{0.5in}#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \setcaptionsubtype
        \begin{groupplot}[%
            ,group style={%
                ,group name=my plots
                ,group size=2 by 3
                ,vertical sep=2cm,
                ,horizontal sep = 2cm,
                ,ylabels at=edge left
                }
            ,width=7cm
            ,height=6cm
            ,try min ticks=5
            ,xlabel={Frequency in \si{\hertz}}
            ,grid=both
            ,every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}
            ]
            \nextgroupplot%
                \addplot[smooth,blue]{rnd};
            \nextgroupplot%
                \addplot[smooth,blue] {rnd};%
                \addplot[mark=*,red,mark options={scale=.65}] {rnd};
        \end{groupplot}
        \node[text width=.5\linewidth,align=center,anchor=south] at (my plots c1r1.north) {\caption{Plot \arabic{subfigure}\label{subplot:one}}};
        \node[text width=.5\linewidth,align=center,anchor=south] at (my plots c2r1.north) {\caption{Plot \arabic{subfigure}\label{subplot:two}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Plot showing Absolute Errors.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \ContinuedFloat
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \setcaptionsubtype
        \begin{groupplot}[%
            ,group style={%
                ,group name=my plots
                ,group size=2 by 3
                ,vertical sep=2cm,
                ,horizontal sep = 2cm,
                ,ylabels at=edge left
            }
            ,width=7cm
            ,height=6cm
            ,try min ticks=5
            ,xlabel={Frequency in \si{\hertz}}
            ,grid=both
            ,every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}
            ]
            \nextgroupplot%
                \addplot[smooth,blue] {rnd};
            \nextgroupplot%
                \addplot[smooth,blue] {rnd};%
                \addplot[mark=*,red,mark options={scale=.65}] {rnd};
            \nextgroupplot%
                \addplot[smooth,blue] {rnd};
            \nextgroupplot%
                \addplot[smooth,blue] {rnd};%
                \addplot[mark=*,red,mark options={scale=.65}] {rnd};
        \end{groupplot}
        \node[text width=.5\linewidth,align=center,anchor=south] at (my plots c1r1.north) {\caption[]{Plot \arabic{subfigure}\label{subplot:three}}};
        \node[text width=.5\linewidth,align=center,anchor=south] at (my plots c2r1.north) {\caption[]{Plot \arabic{subfigure}\label{subplot:four}}};
        \node[text width=.5\linewidth,align=center,anchor=south] at (my plots c1r2.north) {\caption[]{Plot \arabic{subfigure}\label{subplot:five}}};
        \node[text width=.5\linewidth,align=center,anchor=south] at (my plots c2r2.north) {\caption[]{Plot \arabic{subfigure}\label{subplot:six}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[]{Plot showing Absolute Errors. (continued)}\label{abserror}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I use the `\usepackage{subfig}` instead of `\usepackage{caption,subcaption}`, I get the file to compile, however, the subplots reset on the second page and starts from (a) again.    Can this be an alternative start to a solution?

Comment: No, using `subfig` is no alternative here since this package does not offer an equivalent to `\setcaptionsubtype`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution: Just drop the line

```
\newcounter{sublisting}[listing]
```

and everything should be fine. This is not a conflict between the `subcaption` and `pythontex` package, quite the opposite, it's a feature that you actually don't need this line.

Actually this line is wrong two times:

1. `\DeclareCaptionSubType{listing}`

would be the correct line instead, to make the `subcaption` package aware of the `listing` environment. Otherwise features like `\ContinuedFloat` would not work correctly. And

2. The `subcaption` package automatically does `\DeclareCaptionSubType` (which defines sub-counters) for every floating environment known by the `caption` package bundle. So trying to re-define the already existing counter `sublisting` yields to an error here.

But how is the `caption` package bundle aware of the floating environment `listing`? This is because the `pythontex` package uses `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` offered by the `newfloat` package to define its floating environment `listing`, and the `newfloat` package is part of the `caption` package bundle. So in fact

```
\setpythontexlistingenv{listing}
```

defines the counter `sublisting` additionally for you if the `subcaption` package is used, no need to do this for yourself.

A hint about this could be found within the `subcaption` package manual, explaining `\DeclareCaptionSubType`:

"For the environments figure & table, and all the ones defined with \DeclareFloatingEnvironment offered by the newfloat package, this will be done automatically, but for other environments (e.g. the ones defined with \newfloat offered by the float package or \DeclareNewFloatType offered by the floatrow package) this has to be done manually."